# Script to loop through files except certain files

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I'm trying to loop through all `HTML` files in a directory.

The following works just fine for that.

```
for f in *.html; do echo $f; done
```

But, how can I add an `if` condition so that the file name is only echoed if it is not equal to `index.html`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be simple like:

```
for f in *.html
do 
    if [ "$f" != "index.html" ]
    then
        echo $f
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for f in *.html; do  [ "$f" != "index.html" ] && echo "$f"; done
```

Answer (score 1):

It's also possible to exclude `index.html` from the list entirely with [extended globbing](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html):

```
shopt -s extglob nullglob
for f in !(index).html; do
    echo "$f"
done
```

- `shopt -s extglob`: enables extended globbing
- `shopt -s nullglob`: makes sure the loop is not executed should there be no matching files
- `!(index).html`: expands to all `html` files that are not `index.html`

Comment: I like this approach, but it's not working.  `zsh: no matches found: !(index).html`

Comment: @RaphaelRafatpanah Why did you tag the question with `bash` when you are using `zsh`?

Comment: Because I'm planning to run this on a machine without `zsh`

Comment: @RaphaelRafatpanah then you can't be surprised this doesn't work on `zsh`.

Comment: On bash `4.4.12` I get `-bash: !: event not found`??

Comment: That's fair. I didn't know that some `bash` scripts wouldn't work in `zsh`

Comment: @RaphaelRafatpanah Equivalent in `zsh` is `^(index).html` by the way.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Do you have `extglob` enabled?

Comment: Yep `shopt -s extglob nullglob; for f in !(index).php; do echo "$f"; done` (yes I have `.php` files instead of `.html`)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Possible issue: `shopt` must be on a separate line. Because `extglob` changes the way the line is parsed.

Comment: @RaphaelRafatpanah `bash` and `zsh` are different. If you want to deploy a script on a machine with `bash`, better test it with `bash` :)

Comment: I've seen stranger things. I have no doubt it works, but I think (according to the man page) `! starts a history substitution ... when the extglob shell option is enabled using the shopt builtin` So I'm confused how setting `extglob` allows `!(index)` to work?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin When you read the whole thing, it says: `...except when followed by a space ... or ‘(’ (when the extglob shell option is enabled ...)`. So if you have `!` followed by `(`, it is not considered history substitution (if `extglob` is enabled) :)

Comment: Ahh, that's what I was missing in the man page, my terminal width causes the `(` to be alone at the end of the line before the next line containing `(when the extglob shell option is enabled using the shopt builtin)`. That said, it still pukes when using `!(index)`, I'll have time to play with it later.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Only thing I see as a possible culprit is the `shopt` not being on a separate line :)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I may have given a wrong explanation before. Quoting manual: `History expansion is performed immediately after a complete line is read, before the shell breaks it into words.` So history expansion is done before the `shopt` is executed = `shopt` has to be on a separate line.

Comment: Yes, I went ahead and threw it into a script and you are correct -- it works fine. (that makes it hard to turn it into a one-liner `:)`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Yep :) Although, I don't see a reason not to have `extglob` enabled by default.